# Reading a file that changes using FileReader

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

I have an application that generates JSON-based documents.  For complicated reasons, the output of that application is often imperfect and needs minor manual corrections.  We wrote a validator to detect cases where manual corrections may be needed; users can then choose whether or not to make them.  The validator was written as a simple HTML+JS page that users clone from git and load from a file: URL.

Here is a simplified version of the validator, omitting all of the UI, error handling, and data parsing logic:

```js
function loadFile() {
  var filePath;
  var reader;

  document.getElementById("validation_output").innerHTML = "";
  filePath = document.getElementById("fileinput");
  reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = receivedText;
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(filePath.files[0]);
}

function receivedText(e) {
  document.getElementById("validation_output").textContent = "Successfully read from file!";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="file" id="fileinput">
    <input type="button" value="Validate File" onclick="loadFile()">
  </div>
  <div id="validation_output">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In normal use, a user uses the file input to select a file, then clicks "Validate" to run the validation.  If the file fails validation, then the user makes edits to the file out of band, then clicks "Validate" again to see if the changes corrected the problems.

The problem is that while the validator works on the initial validation pass, it fails on the second pass if the file changed.  The browser doesn't throw an exception or log an error to the console; it just never makes the `onload` callback.  This only happens if the contents of the file change; if I re-validate an unchanged document, then it works as expected.  The only work-around that I've identified is to re-load the page and use the file input to select the file again.

How can I make the validator re-load the input file on the second pass?

Comment: I added a `reader.onerror` handler. It's getting this error: **The requested file could not be read, typically due to permission problems that have occurred after a reference to a file was acquired.**

Comment: That was Chrome. I was also able to reproduce it on Firefox, but only if I clicked Validate without re-selecting the file.

Comment: It seems like the browsers are caching a reference to the file, and if the file's properties change it won't reuse that reference. Seems like a browser bug to me.

Comment: Apparently it's a feature, not a bug: if the "snapshot state" of a file changes after its selection, then the file cannot be read. 
 https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#ErrorAndException.  

This makes sense for attempts to upload to a website; the website should not be able to cache the file reference then retrieve changes made to the file later.  It seems like overkill for files loaded from the same origin as the web page.  But either way, this is a dead end.

Comment: That's supposed to detect if the file changed after you selected it, which explains the Firefox behavior. But if you re-select the file after it changed, it shouldn't trigger the error. The bug is that it's reusing the old snapshot state when you select the file a second time.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way around the limitations of FileReader (like its problems to access a chosen file after it has changed).

**Solution:**

The majority of current browsers (except Firefox) now supports the new  [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

Here is an example on how to use it with changing files.
**Unfortunately you will NOT be able to RUN this snippet within Stackoverflow, because showOpenFilePicker() is not allowed in sandboxed documents.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script>
          let fileHandle;
          async function selectFile() {
              [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
              let filenameDiv = document.getElementById('filenameDiv');
              filenameDiv.innerHTML = fileHandle.name;
              readFile();
          };

          async function readFile() {
              const file = await fileHandle.getFile();
              const contents = await file.text();
              let outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
              outputDiv.innerHTML = contents;
          }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div style="margin: 20px;">
          <p><button onclick="selectFile()">Choose template file</button></p>
          <p><button onclick="readFile()">Reload</button></p>
          <div id="filenameDiv" style="background: #fff;"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="outputDiv" style="background: #fff; min-height: 100px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting, but too new.  Maybe in another year or two.

Comment: @user3553031 well, in many cases local file access will actually be required in a very controlled environment (like inside your own company) where you exactly know which browsers are in use. So IMHO there's no reason to wait in such cases.

Comment: Lack of Firefox and Safari support is a blocker for now: https://caniuse.com/?search=showOpenFilePicker